# How to test with DomainUnitTest when multiTenancy

Tags: grails, grails-orm, spock

How do test domain classes when I use multiTenancy?

I can see that I need to extend with HibernateSpec and overwrite getConfiguration.

This goes okay when I use ServiceUnitTest but not for DomainUnitTest

Simple example:
application.yml is setup with:

```
grails:
    gorm:
        multiTenancy:
            mode: DISCRIMINATOR
            tenantResolverClass: security.CompanyTenantResolver
```

My test:

```
class TestSpec extends HibernateSpec implements DomainUnitTest<Test>{
    void "expect ok test"() {
        expect:
        true
    }
    def setup() {
        System.setProperty(SystemPropertyTenantResolver.PROPERTY_NAME, 'unit-test')
    }

    def cleanup() {
        System.setProperty(SystemPropertyTenantResolver.PROPERTY_NAME, '')
    }


    @Override
    Map getConfiguration() {
        [(Settings.SETTING_MULTI_TENANT_RESOLVER_CLASS): SystemPropertyTenantResolver]
    }

}
```

No matter what I try i get:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.grails.beans.ConstraintsEvaluator': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'grailsDomainClassMappingContext' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsDatastore': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.grails.datastore.mapping.simple.SimpleMapDatastore]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Class<?>]
```

Is it a error in grails or have forgotten something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is a error in grails version 3.3.2 works okay in version 3.3.0